# Making Tizen.TV.UIControls work on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, tizen

I'm developing a gallery with images from a webserver that I host. The thing is I want to navigate between the images using the controller of the TV (the remote). I tried the sample Tizen provided on GitHub :

https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.TV.UIControls/wiki/Introducing-Tizen.TV.UIControls 
https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.TV.UIControls

But I can't make them work. Everytime I try to implement it, I get this error :

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Tizen.ExportRendererAttribute' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Tizen, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(QCallModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll(Type[] attrTypes, InitializationFlags flags)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetupInit(CoreApplication application, Nullable`1 maybeOptions)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(CoreApplication application, Boolean useDeviceIndependentPixel)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(CoreApplication application)
   at Gallery.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Mow\Source\Repos\ceffDptInfo\tizen_gallery\Gallery.Tizen.TV\Gallery.Tizen.TV.cs:line 18
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Google is your friend - https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API is broken on Xamarin.forms 4.2.0 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.2/4.2.0-api#removed-type-xamarinformsplatformtizenexportrendererattribute

Before release a new version of Tizen.TV.UIControls, you can only use under Xamarin.forms 4.1.x version